# Let $\left(X,\,\|\cdot\|\right)$ be a norm space and $\{e_1,...,e_k\}$ be a linearly independents set:

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Show that there exist a $\beta\ge 0$ such that for every scalar set $\{c_1,...,c_k\}$

$\left\|\sum_{i=1}^kc_i e_i \right\|\ge \beta \cdot\left\lvert\sum_{i=1}^kc_i \right\rvert$

Can you help me to prove this...

Comment: Just a small thought. Take, $ e_{min} = \text{min} \{e_1, e_2, \dots , e_k \} $ and $\|e_{min}\|=\beta$. Minimum in the sense of minimum norm value.

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to prove that $\exists \beta \geq 0$ such that for any scalars $\{c_1,c_2,\ldots, c_k\}$,
$$
\left\| \sum_{i=1}^k c_ie_i \right\| \geq \beta \sum_{i=1}^k |c_i|
$$

Suppose not, then there would exist scalars $c_1^{(m)}, c_2^{(m)}, \ldots, c_k^{(m)}$ such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k |c_i^{(m)}| = 1
$$
and
$$
\|\sum_{i=1}^k c_i^{(m)}e_i\| < 1/m
$$
Now the sequence $(c_i^{(m)})_{m\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, so by Bolzano-Weierstrass, has a convergent subsequence. The limits give scalars $c_1,c_2,\ldots, c_k$ such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k |c_i| =1 \qquad (\ast)
$$
and by continuity of the norm
$$
\|\sum_{i=1}^k c_i e_i\| = 0
$$
This implies that $\sum_{i=1}^k c_i e_i = 0$, which, together with $(\ast)$, contradicts the linear independence of $\{e_i : 1\leq i\leq k\}$

Comment: do this problem relation with Riesz lemma in functional analysis?

Comment: @b.balal: How? The Riesz Lemma I know refers to producing vectors at a fixed distance from a closed subspace.